# How to show ColumnKey on bar in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

[image]

I have a stacked bar chart like in the image above. What i need is to show column keys ("Series 1","Series 2","Series 3") on the bars instead of their values. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
            new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{0}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

The label generator works off a template where it replaces instances of '{0}' with the series name, '{1}' with the category key, and '{2}' with the data value.  The number formatter passed to the constructor is used for formatting the data values (but in your case, the data value is not displayed so the formatter will not be used).

Comment: Thanks, that works. But i'm confused about one thing. How can i show total value at top of the bar while the columns still on the bars?

Comment: There is an example for that in the JFreeChart demo collection (StackedBarChartDemo3.java).  It uses a subclass of the StackedBarRenderer.  The source code for this is included with the JFreeChart Developer Guide which I sell to provide (at least some) funding for the project.